# How can I build the mongoose web server on Linux?

Tags: c, mongoose-web-server

I apologize if this seems like a stupid question, but I guess I am more used to packages that come with Makefiles or configure scripts.

I downloaded the Mongoose source tar file from the [site](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/downloads/list), and untarred it.

I then tried to compile an executable out of it using
`gcc -g -c mongoose.c -o main.o -lpthread  -ldl`. 
However, after trying to execute,  I get the error `-bash: ./main.o: cannot execute binary file`

When I looked into mongoose.c source, I did not find a main function.

Where can I get the main function so that the Linux mongoose web server can be compiled to work the same way as the Windows `mongoose.exe`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongoose does come with a Makefile, and will compile as a standalone command-line program. Lua and SQLite are included.

The easiest way to compile the latest version is to cd into the "build" directory and run `make unix`. I'm not sure about the archived version on the downloads page, but trunk has been pretty stable.

I just checked out a clean copy of Mongoose from github earlier tonight and built it with no problems, so I can confirm that this works (assuming you have any other dependencies set up properly, of course).

Comment: Mongoose no longer has a ./build directory, and the developer isn't very helpful, possibly because Mongoose is now partly a commercial product.

Comment: @Gulbahar you probably already know this but the [Civetweb](https://github.com/bel2125/civetweb) fork retains the MIT license, is actively developed, and has detailed [build instructions](https://github.com/bel2125/civetweb/blob/master/docs/Building.md).

Answer (score 1):

It's because mongoose is not supposed to be used standalone, but to "embed" it into your program. You need to create a program which calls the correct function from `mongoose.c`.

Also, the `-c` flag to GCC tells it to create an *object file*, which needs to be linked to create an executable. So you try to execute a file which is not executable.

Comment: Why does the windows version of mongoose come with a standalone program while the *nix version does not?
I expected a *nix version to include a standalone build for that reason.

Comment: @merlin2011 source code archive have no main function so it cannot be fully the same thing used in provided windows executable (which contains a lot other things like SSL, lua, etc. - none of them are part of core mongoose source code). The only one who could answer your question is developer/maintainer of their windows bundle, please ask them if you like to - although i wouldn't be surprised if you'll be the first one who wanted this functionality, it's certainly not mongoose intended use case.